# Quoted text: pathetically pale

Tags: feature-request, user-interface

Quoted text is indicated by a grey vertical bar to the left of the quoted text.

The text of the quote is shown in an *even paler* grey, for example:

---

[image: Example of low-contrast colouring]

---

Is there a reason  that something which is already called out needs to be obscured so that it is difficult to read?

Please could we have easily-readable text in *all* circumstances?

<sub>(I disabled f.lux to look at this.)</sub>

Comment: This brings back a faint memory of the Yellow box :)

Comment: See [Some improvements to blockquotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/343919) for more details.

Comment: Personally, I think it should be lighter than normal text, so that there's some contrast. I don't think it should be _too_ light, but some contrast like there is right now would be good.

Comment: Related: Samuel Liew's [Reduce Clutter userscript](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts#reduce-clutter) reverts the quotes back to the old (and good looking, imo) [pale yellow color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GnVfN.png), among many other style tweaks.

Comment: The color used there is #535a60, which has a contrast ratio with the background color, #fafafb, of 6.71:1, which [passes WCAG AA, but fails WCAG AAA](https://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/?fcolor=535A60&bcolor=FAFAFB). Personally, I'd call that "readable", but perhaps not "easily readable".